# Авторизация на outlook через curl php

Tags: php, curl, outlook

Как реализовать вход через outlook через Curl на php.
Я новичок в этом вопросе.

Comment: А какая стоит задача? Если получить/отправить почту то Curl не нужен.

Comment: Нужно только узнать он правильно ввел свои адрес и пароль от почты. То есть нужно получить ответ от сервера типа как "Success"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По уточненной в комментариях задачи вероятно CURL не нужен, достаточно IMAP (если конечно он в outlook) включен по умолчанию. Реализация примерно такая:

```
$hostname = '{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password'; 

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to '.$hostname.': ' . imap_last_error());
```